# Raspberry Pi 3 Alexa error: Unable to load library 'vlc'

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I tried to install Alexa Voice Service on my Raspberry Pi 3 by following these instructions:https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi.

On step seven (terminal window 2) when I run the command:

```
cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec
```

I get the error

> The error was "Unable to load library 'vlc': Native library

followed by a huge path. I also tried running the command as :

```
mvn exec:exec "-Dalpn-boot.version=8.1.6.v20151105"
```

but that also yielded the same error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: My Java version is:
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and tried to install the VLC library but it just said I already have the latest version. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

### Install VLC Library

It's probably trying to use the VLC library, but it's not installed.

To Install: `sudo apt-get install libvlc5`

Answer (score 0):

Installing the dev version fixed the problem for me.

```
sudo apt install libvlc-dev
```